# UIPickerView scrolls to the end when clicking outside

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uipickerview

I am creating a picker view like this(nothing special):

```
        var picker = new UIPickerView();
        picker.Model = new DropDownPickerViewModel(items, ItemSelected);
        picker.Select(selected, 0, true);

        InputView = picker;
        InputAccessoryView = null;
```

Method from Model:

```
    public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        itemSelectedEvent?.Invoke((int)row);
    }
```

When I click on TextField, pickerView opens. I can choose(by scrolling) a value I want, but when I click outside pickerview or oi item it scrolls to the last item and calls Selected method

Comment: It is default behavior . What's your problem ? Remove it ?

Comment: @ColeXia It's not default behaviour. It was a simulator glitch. Restarting helped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind. It was a simulator glitch. restarting helped

Comment: Had been trying to fix this for an hour, and you probably saved me another two! Thanks!